How to globally turn off equation numbering?
In a very similar way to this post: Global option to turn on/off section numbering, say I have a large document with many equations numbered, some unnumbered using \begin{equation} and \begin{equation*}, and I want a version of the document with all numberings removed. There must be a way to globally change equation -> equation* or something like that?
I had similar problems with section numbering, but was able to resolve that with \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} (though \let\section\section* did not seem to work) as suggested by the linked post.

I will assume that you're interested in disabling not only the numbering of equations created with equation environments, but also the numbering of equations that are created with align, gather, multiline and similar environments. Please advise.

That's right, looking to kill all of them. Your post is fantastic. I fortunately have no references, but I agree the added benefit of your solution is nice.

If you don't want to show any equation numbers, this also means that you won't have any cross-references (which usually include equation numbers) to equations, right?
If this is the case, I suggest you load the mathtools package (a superset of the amsmath package) with the option showonlyrefs=true, i.e., that you run
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}

This approach has an added benefit in case you do decide to cross-reference a few equations: Only those equations that you explicitly cross-reference -- say, via \eqref directives -- will get numbered, while all other equations will remain unnumbered.

In case you add \eqref directives: It'll take three LaTeX runs to get the required equations and associated cross-references to be numbered correctly.

If you are using standard latex classes, put this in your preamble:
\makeatletter
\def\@eqnnum{} 
\makeatother

If you use the ams class or packages, put this in your preamble:
\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{}
\makeatother

If you want to turn off numbering only for certain environments (say, equation), then put this in your preamble:
\renewenvironment{equation}{\[}{\]}

